# Azure policy force routes to routetable

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to create a policy which forces two routes to be on route table. My policy currently is:

```
{
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].name",
                "NotEquals": "myrouteA"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].name",
                "NotEquals": "myrouteB"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
```

But this does not deny the removal of routes. What should I change?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Azure Policy are not used for scenarios - deny removal. Use resource locks to avoid removal of the Route Table.

You can have a plan to have RouteTable with recommended routes by enforcing a policy.

Comment: To support my statement :) check this [out](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915958-azure-governance/suggestions/38693134-azure-policy-based-on-delete-action)

Comment: the point is that I would like end users the ability to add more routes on top of few of my own.

Comment: In that case, you can use policy modify effect. For reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#modify